# How to read file stored in my computer using django view function

Tags: python, django, csv, django-views, cpanel

I have developed and deployed a Django app and trying to update the database table using a locally stored CSV file. Everything is working fine on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ or localhost but when I am deploying the app on Cpanel, the view function stops working.

Here is my code:

```
def getrate(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "GET" :
            with open("C:/djangoapp/xyz.csv", "r", encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as temp_raw:
                temp_raw_reader = csv.reader(temp_raw) 
                for line in temp_raw_reader:
                    rt = Rates_Detail.objects.get(product_id = 111)
                    if rt:
                       rt.product_rate = line[2]
                       rt.save()

            user = request.user
            pd = Rates_Detail.objects.values()
            productdetails = list(pd)
            return JsonResponse({'status':'Save', 'productdetails':productdetails})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

Comment: Does cpanel (or: your app deployed in cpanel) have access to the location `open("C:/djangoapp/xyz.csv",` ? If not, then you probably need to put the csv file somewhere accessible for the app

Comment: @Ralf the code needs to check for the file in the given location.. since I need to update the csv file from my end it should be kept on my local system only. Kindly let me know if you have any idea of doing this

Comment: Is the app on cpanel on the same machine as your CSV file? If not, does the machine with the app have a way to access the CSV file on your machine (sftp, ssh, or something) ?

Comment: @Ralf the app is deployed on GoDaddy server and the file is on my personal computer. I don't know how to access the CSV file using an app which is deployed.

Comment: In that case I suggest creating a file-upload-view where you can upload your csv file and that view reads the file and updates the `Rates_Detail` instances. That way the file will never be stored on disk in the server, just in RAM memory while the file-upload-view is running.

Comment: @Ralf if the data is updated every second in the file and hence in the database then it would create a problem, the process would be slow

Comment: How is the CSV file being updated? By an automatic process? Could that process write directly to the database instead of the CSV?

Comment: @Ralf first the CSV file is being updated by python selenium web scrapping every second then Django view should read the file and update the database.

Comment: Can you move the web scrapping into the same django app on cpanel (I now it is technically possible, the question is if it fits your architecture/infrastructure)? Then the webscrapping can update the database directly. That would probably be the most efficient solution, if you want so frecuent updates.

Comment: @Ralf thanks for the suggestion.. definitely I can move the web scrapping part into Cpanel. but the issue is, it's perfectly working when using on localhost but stops working when deployed on the server. 
Note : The web scrapping using python selenium chrome driver/geckodriver to scrape the data. Kindly provide a solution or reference if you have a source.